# Why i cannot change the video display size larger than 640px width in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, media

I added video from media library to my page from content edit box.
no matter how i change the video size, it always on width:640px; cannot show lager in desktop display. it get smaller if view as mobile view.

I checked the CSS, not sure where to setup or change these in CSS.
My testing page now is on http://54.183.134.28/ you can check the video in about us section.

The code i checked in content edit box and CSS inspect, please help, for some reason i do not want to use Youtube, have to load the video to media library.

my question now is is there any restrict for video display size in wordpress?

```
[video width="1920" height="1080" mp4="http://54.183.134.28/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/City-8248.mp4"][/video]

element.style {
    width: 640px;
}

wp-mediaelement….css?ver=4.8:1
.wp-video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

Comment: what is element.style {width: 640px;}, try to remove it. You video code is right. If you post your page of site we can find some other reason.

Comment: Hi there, it looks like some style added it from wordpress, and the max size is width: 640px. tmy question now is can you make your video size larger than 640px width in wordpress? it goes smaller, but not larger than 640px width...

Comment: Maybe is some plugin that you have installed, or some function of your theme, you must to find who write that "elemen.style"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this css code

```
.flowplayer{max-width:650px;}
```

Then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: thanks, the flowplayer is the plugin i just tried, my problem is the top video which add from media library.